# Method arguments changed Issue

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a method `ErrorLog()` which is being called for about 200 times and has 4 parameters.

Now I want to add 1 more parameter. But when I did so, there are over 200 errors. The new argument is of type `Exception e`.

I can go to every method call & add one argument which is `Exception e`, but that will take lots of time.

Is there any easy way out of this?

I am using VS 2015 Professional.

The new argument is not optional. I need to pass it on every call.

Comment: To avoid this in the future, pass a class (or interface) that contains 4 members. Then if you need to add a new member, the signature of the method doesn't change

Comment: When the new argument is not optional you *have* to change the calling code, don´t you?

Comment: @HimBromBeere Yes...But that is what my question is....Is there any easy way? As what i am passing is same for all the methods.!

Comment: You could try Find and replace `methodname\((.*)\)` and `methodname($1,e)` - no guarantee make a backup

Comment: @Max Good idea, should be an answer I guess.

Comment: I have the Idea of `Find & replace` before posting this question.. And i did the same..Just used Find & Replace for Entire Solution with no regression.!

Comment: What exactly did you *search* and by what did you replace it?

Comment: Find : `ErrorLog(` Replaced by `ErrorLog(e,` & i selected option `Entire Solution` .. i got few errors but they were easily solved.

Answer (score 5):

You have two (actually three) opportunities:

1. define a new overload with the new argument

   ```
   ErrorLog(string arg1, string arg2, string arg3, string arg4) {...}
   ErrorLog(string arg1, string arg2, string arg3, string arg4, Exception e) {...}
   ```

   This way you can also give the user a hint that the method with only four arguments is deprecated and thus should nopt be used further using the `Obsolete`-attribute. Any user that stills uses the "old" behaviour will get a compiler-warning to change the method, however for legacy-code it is guaranteed to work (at least for a given time).

   However you should re-direct the call from the old to the new way providing some default-value for the new argument:

   ```
   ErrorLog(string arg1, string arg2, string arg3, string arg4)
   {
       ErrorLog(args1, arg2, arg3, arg4, null);
   }
   ```
2. define the new argument as optional

   ```
   ErrorLog(string arg1, string arg2, string arg3, string arg4, Exception e = null) 
   {
       if(e == null) //...
   }
   ```
3. as already mentioned change the calling-code for every single call, `Search and replace` makes this fairly easy using the regex-option:

   find: `ErrorLog\((^\)*)\)`
   replace: `ErrorLog($1, e)`

Answer (score 0):

set default value for the last parameter of the function, such as

```
function Errorlog(var1, var2, var3, var4, var5=...)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the calling code for each call.

But *Reshapers's* [Change_Signature](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2016.1/Refactorings__Change_Signature.html) provides an automatic and simple way to change a method signature and update the calls accordingly.